# Two Dimensional Array Java TSP

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, traveling-salesman

I need to figure out how to get the following data into two ArrayLists or arrays...

```
THIS THAT OTHER

 1     2     3 
 4     5     6 
 7     8     9
```

I need the column titles to go into one array or ArrayList, and the integer values to go into a two dimensional array or ArrayList.

Here is my attempt at the Strings:

```
cities = new ArrayList<String>();
String newCities;
newCities = (inFile.nextLine());
String[] stringArray = newCities.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    cities.add(stringArray[i]);
}
System.out.println(cities);
```

I can't figure out how to do the integer values.

Finally, this is for the implementation of a Traveling Salesman Problem so if you can think of a better way to handle this data, let me know! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Scanner` class instead, with its `nextInt()` method:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(YOUR_STRING_WITH_INTS);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
     yourInt = scanner.nextInt()
     yourArrayList.add(yourInt);
}
```

and remember to close the scanner afterwards

```
scanner.close();
```

If you want to add this to an array, scan every line, and use an index variable to count which line it is. You know that you have 3 integers in every line, so using your index, write to adequate "row" of the table.

Comment: Okay so now I have a very long ArrayList of integers. I need to plot it up into a 2D Array.

    while (inFile.hasNextInt()){
  
  int newCost = inFile.nextInt();
  costs.add(newCost);

Comment: Scan every line, and use an index variable to count which line it is. Then write it to adequate "row" of the table. I gave you the solution, should I write all the code, too? ;-) I'll edit this answer